# Matlab/Octave addition, losing digits of precision

Tags: matlab, octave

In Matlab/octave, when I add two numbers, I am losing some of my digits.

```
>>> 23.0 + 0.65850
ans =  23.659
```

How do I get back a double that is `23.65850`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number is being rounded *only* for display purposes. Take a look at the `format` command if you wish to change it.

```
octave> 23 + 0.65850
ans =  23.659
octave> format free
octave> 23 + 0.65850
ans = 23.7
octave> format long g
octave> 23 + 0.65850
ans =              23.6585
```

Take a look at `help format` for the other options but remember, that this *only* affects the display. You are *not* losing any precision.

Comment: There *is* rounding taking place during computation... just not as much as the displayed string suggests.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, but that comes from the use of double. You know what I meant ;)