# Rounding to two decimal places in Octave

Tags: octave, rounding

After a calculation I got 32.073 .I need it to round to 32.07 using Octave.Please can somebody help me?

Comment: did you try searching the web?

Comment: Of course.No proper way to be found.

Comment: You didn't specify if you need the rounded number or just printing it.
The answer depends on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
res = round(100 * 37.073) / 100
```

Comment: It gives 37.070. I need 37.07.Need to drop '3'.

Comment: @AnoAPI you cannot. You either have a floating point like that or an integer (or you write your own class). See [Matlab/Octave addition, losing digits of precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886821/matlab-octave-addition-losing-digits-of-precision/13887079)

Comment: Thank you for the proper directing

Answer (score 3):

you could use the C style printf format.

```
sprintf("%.2f", 32.073)
```

Comment: Not a great solution for matrices though. You would need a nested loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11386211/1271772

Answer (score 1):

You can just type `format bank` in the begining